# Converted c++ code into javascript but return incorrect result

Tags: javascript

Converted c++ code to javascript, however it returns incorrect result. The c++ code is [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/). Below is my code

```
    function CeilIndex(A, l, r, key) {
        var m;

        while( r - l > 1 ) {
            m = l + (r - l)/2;

            if (A[m] >= key) {
                r = m;
            } else {
                l = m;
            }
        }

        return r;
    }


    function LongestIncreasingSubsequenceLength(A, size) {
        var tailTable = new Array(size);
        var len;

        tailTable[0] = A[0];

        len = 1;

        for (var i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if( A[i] < tailTable[0] ) {
                tailTable[0] = A[i];
            } else if( A[i] > tailTable[len-1] ) {
                tailTable[len++] = A[i];
            } else {
                tailTable[CeilIndex(tailTable, -1, len-1, A[i])] = A[i];
            }
        }

        return tailTable;
    }

    var A = [0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15];
    var n = A.length;
    console.log("Length of Longest Increasing Subsequence is: ",  LongestIncreasingSubsequenceLength(A, n));
```

When I execute above code it returns `Length of Longest Increasing Subsequence is:  [0, 4, 2, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 15]` whereas its answer is `[0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15]`

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`m` becomes double in your code. All numbers are represented as doubles internally in JS. Should be truncated to int, I guess?
The following code seems to work.

```
function CeilIndex(A, l, r, key) {
    var m;

    while( r - l > 1 ) {
        m = Math.floor(l + (r - l)/2);

        if (A[m] >= key) {
            r = m;
        } else {
            l = m;
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

Comment: I used Math.floor(), Match.ceil(), Math.round(), Math.trunc() etc and I am still getting incorrect but different answer then above. Now answer is `[0, 1, 3, 7, 11, 15]`

Comment: I get this answer too. And this is the answer the guy in the 1st comment on the link you provided getting. This answer has the same length as `[0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15]`. I think there are more than 1 correct answer.

Comment: Which browser are you testing it on?

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle link to this answer?

Comment: your jsfiddle returns `Length of Longest Increasing Subsequence is: 0,1,3,7,11,15,,,,,,,,,,` somehow.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rco0nLbo/ - if you don't want the `,` don't provide the length to the `tailTable` array. It will grow dynamically.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62100/discussion-between-26ph19-and-dmitry).

Comment: My point is not comma. I mean the answer is incorrect. It is 0,1,3,7,11,15 but actual answer should be 0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15.